# python3 super() new style autocompletion in PyCharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, super

With python3 we no longer need to explicitly set the parent class when calling `super`:

```py
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
```

But it seems that PyCharm doesn't know it, because when I try to autocomplete `super` for some method, it uses old style and I receive this:

```py
def setUp(self):
    super(AutocompleteTestCase, self).setUp()
```

Is there any way to tell PyCharm to use new style, because I could not find one.
**Editor -> General -> Code Completion** doesn't provide any way to add/override custom rules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`super` live template is outdated in PyCharm ([the corresponding ticket in PyCharm's issue tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-26060/Live-templates-Python-super-live-template-should-have-PY3-version-as-well)).

I think you can edit it by hand in **Preferences/Settings | Editor | Live Templates | Python | super**.

[image]